# what to do with response object in react js

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs

i'm working with react to complete the front end of a rest application.

I have json being sent to the front end, and I use fetch .

```
fetch('/task')
  .then(function(data) {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
      json.tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      console.log(task.name)
      })
  });
```

So i'm able to console.log each task.name, but where to now? How do I get my component to display each task as a

?

Basically, where in a component does this type of logic go? Do i save the fetch request to a variable and then setState = variable?

this is my component:

```
class Task extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p> hey </p>
  }
}
```

Comment: setState is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize a state object, which you can update when the fetch is complete:

```
class Task extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()

    this.state {
      tasks: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/task')
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ tasks: json.tasks })
      })
  }

  renderTaskList () {
    if (this.state.tasks) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => <li key={i}>{task.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      )
    }

    return <p>Loading tasks...</p>
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        {this.renderTaskList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: Re-reading this answer, I just wanted to note that it is not necessary to initialize the `tasks` property of the state object in this case. You could also just do something like:

```
this.state = {}
```

However, I think there is some value in explicitly naming the various properties of your state object, even if they are initialized as `null`. This allows you to write components whose state is documented in the constructor, and will prevent you or your teammates from later guessing how a component's state is modeled.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I had to add arrow functions to my fetch function but otherwise this cleared things up for me pretty well.

two questions to follow up:

1. is constructor() , and super() always used when making components, or root level components ?

2. should componentDidMount be used when making http requests?

Comment: These are not always used ... for example, you might have a stateless functional component that not only does not use the constructor, but simply cannot because it is not a class. As for componentDidMount, this is a great place to fetch data. It guarantees that your state has been initialized (constructor fires before this method), and is "isomorphic" in the sense that this component can be rendered by the browser or the server. So if fetch is not in your server environment, it won't fire until running in the browser.